Were unprovable philosophical statements used to enrich the basic beliefs?
As far as I understand, several concepts such as solipsism, free will, simulation hypothsis, existence of higher powers etc can neither be proved nor disproved. Only recently it has come to my mind that it reminds me of a situation in mathematics where some statements happen to be independent from the others, like Axiom of Choice or Continuum Hyptothesis are independent from ZF set of axioms. In maths we then talk about models of set theory - namely a family of axioms which we postulate to be true, we can add to this family anything that keeps its consistent. Following this path, one can enrich their set of "axioms" about the world they live in with any of the statements above making them either false or true depending on the personal choice. I'm pretty sure I'm not the first to see this similarity, so I wonder who studied it and if it has become the state of the art way of dealing with the philosophical concepts that can neither be proved nor disproved.

As it stands, I believe this question doesn't really make much sense -- it's very unclear to me what the question is. There are endless disputes in philosophy. This doesn't imply that clearly this or that (solipsism, etc) can or can not "be proved". There is only a superficial, apparent analogy here with math. People try to make their assumptions clear, and sometimes do present more formal frameworks -- but when those actually succeed they are math.  People try to do sth like conceptual analysis, but it doesn't make sense, imo, to talk about "proving concepts" or "unprovable concepts".


Yes, in mathematics you can enrich a given system of axioms by
adding further axioms if the latter are consistent among each other
and with the original axiom system.

As you propose, the same can be done with the axioms of a given
world model.
But remember: Axioms of a world model are axioms, i.e.
presuppositions or assumptions, not checked results from a
scientific theory. The burden of checking the enriched world model
remains and has increased.



Sure, I agree with the burden being on the proposal of the world models. My question however is whether this approach was analyzed specifically or is it an obvious one everyone uses explicitly

@SBF IMO this approach is practized indeed without further ado.

Here is Heidegger's unprovable basic à priori axiom:

Dasein is an entity which, in its very [existence], comports itself
understandingly towards [its existence]. In saying this, we are
calling attention to the formal concept of existence. Dasein exists.
Furthermore, Dasein is an entity which in each case I myself am.
Mineness belongs to any existent Dasein, and belongs to it as the
condition which makes authenticity and inauthenticity possible. In
each case Dasein exists in one or the other of these two modes
[authentic or inauthentic], or else it is modally undifferentiated.
... these are both ways in which Dasein's Being takes on a definite
character, and they must be seen and understood a priori as grounded
upon that state of Being which we have called "Being-in-the-world". B&T
53


When one talks [critically] of the 'circle' in understanding, one expresses a
failure to recognize two things: (1) that understanding as such makes
up a basic kind of Dasein's Being, and (2) that this Being is
constituted as care. To deny the circle,
to make a secret of it, or even to want to overcome it, means finally
to reinforce this failure. We must rather endeavour to leap into the
'circle', primordially and wholly, so that even at the start of the
analysis of Dasein we make sure that we have a full view of Dasein's
circular Being. B&T
315-6


Ontological inquiry is indeed more primordial, as over
against the ontical3 inquiry of the positive sciences. But
it remains itself naïve and opaque if in its researches into the Being
of entities it fails to discuss the meaning of Being in general. And
even the ontological task of constructing a non-deductive genealogy of
the different possible ways of Being requires that we first come to an
understanding of 'what we really mean by this expression "Being"'.
The question of Being aims therefore at ascertaining the a priori
conditions not only for the possibility of the sciences which examine
entities as entities of such and such a type, and, in so doing,
already operate with an understanding of Being, but also for the
possibility of those ontologies themselves which are prior to the
ontical sciences and which provide their foundations.  (Being &
Time, H.11)


I've found it rather hard to comprehend what he means, please forgive my lack of training in reading and undersatnding philsophy. Would you care to explain from your pov how these lines are relevant to the OP?

It is the prime example of basic "philosophical concepts that can neither be proved nor disproved". It serves as the foundation of all the others (including mathematics), but itself unavoidably has to be taken à priori.

I am not sure if concepts such as solipsism, the simulation hypothsis or the existence of higher powers, have an axiomatic nature. They are rather metaphysical theories.
The problem with these theories is that they have minimal explanatory capacity and are not falsifiable. They are 'just so' solutions. If you can't solve a problem in mathematics you could leave out an axiom like, for example, the parallel postulate to obtain non-Euclidean geometry. If you add an axiom you have to check the validity of all theorems downstream..
I think free will is a different category altogether.

Axiom: "a statement or proposition which is regarded as being established, accepted, or self-evidently true." Merriam-Webster. I would have said "cogito ergo sum" was an axiom if it were not for Heidegger's reworking of it, (at B&T 211).

@ChrisDegnen do you concur the opinion of the post author or correct it?

@ChrisDegnen You are right, I think I was used to a narrower definition, or use, of the word axiom, but if this is the definition, yes, then God is an axiom. One axiom to rule them all..

@SBF I don't think solipcism (nor probably the others) is coherent so there is nothing to prove or disprove. At least a theory has to make sense first, and then it may yet prove unproveable. Under a valid axiom there could be parallel sub-axioms. They don't seem to be immutable though. New things come along.

@ChrisDegnen Aren't all axioms unprovable?

@Philomath Indeed, you are correct.  "They are really just assertions or propositions to which we give a special primal status and exempt from the necessity of independent proof." What's an Axiom. Heidegger connects the mathematical with knowledge in this essay where he writes: "The highest principle is the "I" principle: cogito—sum. It is the fundamental axiom of all knowledge; but it is not the only fundamental axiom, ... "

"Since the mathematical as the axiomatic project posits itself as the authoritative principle of knowledge, the positing is thereby established as the thinking, as the "I think," the I-principle." Modem Science, Metaphysics, and Mathematics, page 281.

@ChrisDegnen I think I get: if an axiom is self-evidently true, than there must be someone or something to whom it is self-evidently true.

Coincidentally I recently read: "We have already taken note of Aristotle's striking thesis about the being-true of the logos, assertion … According to it the being-true of assertion is οὐκ ἐν πράγμασιν, not in things, but ἐν διανοίᾳ, in the understanding, in intellectu, as Scholasticism puts it. … Here, too, we have to ask, What does "truth is in the understanding" mean? … we come back again to the question about the mode of being of the understanding" Basic Problems of Phenomenology, page 214.

Well, that brings us to the problem of intentionality, or aboutness, of our understanding (whether self-evident or not) of an axiom. I need to study Heidegger more...

@Philomath Re "if an axiom is self-evidently true, than there must be someone or something to whom it is self-evidently true": over the years, I have heard quite a few allegedly self-evidently true propositions that might be someone's axioms. but not mine... It seems unlikely that each such proposition is consistent with all the others.

@sdenham Somebody broke maths...
